# Set each items BackColor property of a ComboBox

Tags: winforms, powershell, combobox

Here's the code I have so far below which is populated with an array `([System.Drawing.Color] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Properties).name`.

I was trying to see if there was any way to set the `BackColor` property of each item to match that of the same array element of colours but there's none.

Ideally, I'd like to get something like this with a little swatch of the colours to the left of the name.

**EDIT:**
I've since found that you can add an event handler for the control but I'm still unsure how to change each item to show a little swatch. I've updated the code below as the other coded wasn't that close.

[image]

### The code I have so far:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Font            = [System.Drawing.Font]::New("Segoe UI", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular) # Bold, Italic, Regular, Strikeout or Underline
$Form.StartPosition   = 'CenterScreen'
$Form.Text            = 'How do I Change Each Items Colour to Match Their Name?'
$Form.Width           = 500
$Form.Height          = 69
$Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle # 1 A fixed, single-line border
$Form.SizeGripStyle   = [System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle]::Hide # 2 The sizing grip is hidden.

$combo                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$combo.DrawMode           = 'OwnerDrawFixed'
$combo.FlatStyle          = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::System
$combo.Font               = [System.Drawing.Font]::New("Segoe UI", 14, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular) # Bold, Italic, Regular, Strikeout or Underline
$combo.Width              = $Form.Width-1-$combo.Height+($combo.Margin.Left+$combo.Margin.Right)
$combo.AutoCompleteMode   = 'SuggestAppend' # Enables searching but not mid string. Need to find a solution for this.
$combo.AutoCompleteSource = 'ListItems'
$combo.AutoSize           = $true
$combo.DropDownStyle      = 'DropDownList'
$combo.ItemHeight         = 24

$colorNamesArr = ([System.Drawing.Color] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Properties).name # Here's the array of colour that are to get added to the ComboBox.
$combo.Items.AddRange($colorNamesArr) # Add the array to the ComboBox.
$Form.Controls.Add($combo)

# HERE'S WHERE I NEED HELP.

# How do I change the colours of the ComboBox items to match that of their name.

$combo.Add_DrawItem({param($sender,$e)
    $text = "-- Select Color --"
    if ($e.Index -gt -1){
        $text = $sender.GetItemText($sender.Items[$e.Index])
    }
    $e.DrawBackground()

    [System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer]::DrawText($e.Graphics, $text, $combo.Font, $e.Bounds, $e.ForeColor, [System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags]::Default)

})
$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$Form.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the event that draws the ComboBox. Here is a sample of how you might do it, if you wanted to add a colour next to each name.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$Form.Text          = "How do I Change Each Items Colour to Match Their Name?"
$Form.Width         = 500
$Form.Height        = 72

$cbSearch               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$cbSearch.Font          = [System.Drawing.Font]::New("Segoe UI", 14, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular) # Bold, Italic, Regular, Strikeout or Underline
$cbSearch.Width         = $Form.Width-1-$cbSearch.Height+($cbSearch.Margin.Left+$cbSearch.Margin.Right)
$cbSearch.DropDownStyle = 'DropDownList'

# Setting up the ComboBox.
$colorNamesArr = ([System.Drawing.Color] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Properties).name
#Add the array to the ComboBox.
$colorNamesArr | ForEach-Object {[void] $cbSearch.Items.Add($_)}
#Set the first item when opened.
$cbSearch.Text = $colorNamesArr[0]

## Allow override of graphical rendering of the Combobox.
$cbSearch.DrawMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode]::OwnerDrawFixed

## Add an event that draws each item.
$cbSearch.add_DrawItem({
    param([object]$s, [System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs]$e)

    $Graphics = $e.Graphics
    $Rectangle = $e.Bounds
    # Clear the previous drawing
    $e.DrawBackground()
    if ($e.Index -ge 0) {
        $Name = ([System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]$s).Items[$e.Index].ToString()
        $Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
        $Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName($Name)
        $Brush = [System.Drawing.SolidBrush]::new($Color)
        # Can uncomment this if you do not want the background highlighted when hovering over item.
        # $Graphics.TextRenderingHint = [System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint]::AntiAliasGridFit
        $Graphics.DrawString($Name, $Font, [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black, $Rectangle.X, $Rectangle.Top)
        $Graphics.FillRectangle($Brush, $Rectangle.X + 110, $Rectangle.Y + 5, $Rectangle.Width -10, $Rectangle.Height -10)

        # Dispose of disposable objects
        $Brush.Dispose()
    }
})

# Add any controls to the form.
$Form.Controls.Add($cbSearch)

# This below needs to be added to focus the dialog when it opens after the ColorDialog.
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate(); $cbSearch.Focus()})

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Play around with the settings to change the drawing to your preference.

Adapted to PowerShell from [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34332/Color-Picker-Combo-Box-2).

---

**EDIT**

If you want to change the position and size of the coloured boxes, see this example.

```
$Graphics.DrawString($Name, $Font, [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black, $Rectangle.X + 40, $Rectangle.Top + 5)
$Graphics.FillRectangle($Brush, $Rectangle.X + 10, $Rectangle.Y + 2, $Rectangle.Width - 440, $Rectangle.Height - 4)
```

X and Y cover the positioning within the box of an object. Height and Width is the size of the box itself.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Do you know what's causing the item name to go slightly fuzzy and bold when you hover over the item? See here: https://i.imgur.com/8vKZufm.png

Comment: I think the text is being redrawn as you hover over it, giving it the slightly blurry look.

Comment: I've tried to add `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods but it's still there.

Comment: Sorry, had to do something else quick. Try that out now.

Comment: No worries. That doesn't highlight the items when you dropdown the ComboBox which was something the first one did also. I've added `$e.DrawBackground()` after `$Rectangle = $e.Bounds` and that's resolved the issue. So if you want to add that to the answer and I'll accept it that would be great. I'm still unsure how to get the swatches over to the left side with the text beside it to the right but I'm looking into that now.

Comment: I've left the antialiasing in commented out in case people do not want the weird blue highlighting when they hover over items.))

Comment: Thanks, I'll continue to try to get the swatch over on the left as per the example in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see the updated answer with a sample of how to move the colour over to the left.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ash.

Comment: I already had this answer upvoted but just wanted to say your answer is awesome, it's really cool to see how C# code gets translated to PS code. Thanks! One question, is this possible to do without a `param (...)` block? I usually use `$_` and `$this` but I sometimes find it hard to understand which one is the event and which one is the sender...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It has to be a ScriptBlock with the params that reflects the method ([DrawItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem?view=net-5.0)) that you would use  in dotnet. I have seen some people use [Register-ObjectEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7.1), but I think it's simpler with a ScriptBlock. You should always have Sender and Event in that order, so a lot of people will declare the params as `sender/s` and `event/e` for clarity.

Comment: Sometimes you will see events without the params, because people are just reacting to the event and not doing anything with the item that triggered it i.e. Click here to run script.